# Hashed passcode matching stuck python

Tags: python, tkinter, freeze

I am doing a fun little project, making a kind of secret code program with a GUI(Tkinter) to encrypt my text(not very securely). I am trying to make a password on this program linked to a txt file. The program has default password 'abc', stored in a text file in sha-224. When the user enters 'abc', it will hash their input in sha-224, and compare it to the stored password in _hexutf2.txt. Once they have logged in, the user will have the option to choose a new password by clicking New Passcode, entering their previous passcode, clicking next, and then clicking new code. After clicking new code, the user enters a new passcode in the entrypassVariable, then clicks enter passcode, which will write the new passcode on the txt file. Instead, the program hangs on the first pressing of Enter passcode, despite the fact that I had entered 'abc' the default passcode. The program worked before I added the password element, so I will post only the password code here, but I will link to the entire program if anyone wants to see it.

***EDIT***

Posting just the essential code here. The problem in my main program is caused by this. For some reason, this program prints this:

```
Stored Password: cd62248424c8057fea8fff161ec753d7a29f47a7d0af2036a2e79632

Enter Password: Moo
Password Attempt Hash: cd62248424c8057fea8fff161ec753d7a29f47a7d0af2036a2e79632
Password Incorrect
```

http://snipplr.com/view/75865/cryptographer/   <----Entire program code

```
import hashlib

passfile = open('pass.txt','r')
stored_password = str(passfile.read())
print 'Stored Password: ' + stored_password
password = raw_input('Enter Password: ')
enter_pass_sha = hashlib.sha224(password)
enter_password = str(enter_pass_sha.hexdigest())
print 'Password Attempt Hash: ' + enter_password
if stored_password == enter_password:
    print 'Password Correct'
else:
    print 'Password Incorrect'
```

Comment: Sorry in advance to anyone reading this. I'm a dreadful programmer and this was written on and off over 6 months so it's pretty disorganized, with lots of clutter and things I added then forgot why.

Comment: Per my comments on your previous question, this would all be *so much easier* if you spent a bit of time refactoring to separate the GUI out. You could then test small functions in isolation, and if you still got stuck could ask a question with a decent [minimal example](http://sscce.org), so others don't have to trawl through unrelated code.

Comment: It worked in my original simple program that only verifies the password, without a GUI, but when I put that code into my overall program, it stopped working, leading me to think it was a problem in the way coded the GUI.

Comment: My point exactly; if the GUI and the other logic were separate, it would be easier to tell which one the problem was in. Leave the non-GUI code in separate functions, and *call them* from the GUI.

Comment: Separating GUI from code.

Comment: Well not quite, the GUI involves code too, but you could make them separate scripts and `import` (then you could even make e.g. a command line interface later).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58721/discussion-between-bretsky-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have noticed this:

```
Stored Password: cd62248424c8057fea8fff161ec753d7a29f47a7d0af2036a2e79632
    # blank line?!
Enter Password: Moo
Password Attempt Hash: cd62248424c8057fea8fff161ec753d7a29f47a7d0af2036a2e79632
Password Incorrect
```

When you `read` the `stored_password` in from the `passfile`, it comes with a newline character `'\n'` at the end. You need to do:

```
with open('pass.txt') as passfile:
    stored_password = passfile.read().strip()
print 'Stored Password: ' + stored_password
```

Note `str.strip`, called without arguments, removes all whitespace, including newlines, from the start and end of the string. Note also the use of the `with` context manager for file handling, which handles errors and closes the file for you.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is `hexCode = passfile.read` - that's a bound method, not a string (you never called it with `()`). This will not match any of your strings, and causes an exit from OnPassClick or OnNextClick, or a funny message from OnNewClick. Similarly, you raised the class SystemExit type instead of an instance of it.

Comment: Still encountering problem. @jonrsharpe I removed the code for the GUI, the error seems to be in matching the password to the hash.